# Reduce thread competition by using notify in place of notifyAll

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, blockingqueue

I saw this self implemented bounded `blocking queue`.
A change was made to it, aiming to eleminate competition by replacing `notifyAll` with `notify`.

But I don't quite get what's the point of the 2 extra variables added: `waitOfferCount` and `waitPollCount`.
Their initial values are both 0.

Diff after and before they're added is below:
`Offer`:
[image]

`Poll`:
[image]

My understanding is that the 2 variables purpose is that you won't do useless `notify` calls when there's nothing `wait` on the object. But what harm would it do if not done this way?
Another thought is that they may have something to do with the switch from `notifyAll` to `notify`, but again I think we can safely use `notify` even without them?

Full code below:

```java
class FairnessBoundedBlockingQueue implements Queue {
    protected final int capacity;

    protected Node head;

    protected Node tail;

    // guard: canPollCount, head
    protected final Object pollLock = new Object();
    protected int canPollCount;
    protected int waitPollCount;

    // guard: canOfferCount, tail
    protected final Object offerLock = new Object();
    protected int canOfferCount;
    protected int waitOfferCount;

    public FairnessBoundedBlockingQueue(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.canPollCount = 0;
        this.canOfferCount = capacity;
        this.waitPollCount = 0;
        this.waitOfferCount = 0;
        this.head = new Node(null);
        this.tail = head;
    }

    public boolean offer(Object obj) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (offerLock) {
            while (canOfferCount <= 0) {
                waitOfferCount++;
                offerLock.wait();
                waitOfferCount--;
            }
            Node node = new Node(obj);
            tail.next = node;
            tail = node;
            canOfferCount--;
        }
        synchronized (pollLock) {
            ++canPollCount;
            if (waitPollCount > 0) {
                pollLock.notify();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Object poll() throws InterruptedException {
        Object result;
        synchronized (pollLock) {
            while (canPollCount <= 0) {
                waitPollCount++;
                pollLock.wait();
                waitPollCount--;
            }

            result = head.next.value;
            head.next.value = null;
            head = head.next;
            canPollCount--;
        }
        synchronized (offerLock) {
            canOfferCount++;
            if (waitOfferCount > 0) {
                offerLock.notify();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but `notifyAll` will probably send a notification to all waiters that a resource is available, and then all waiters will compete for getting the resource. `notify` will just awaken a single waiter out of many waiters. But, I can be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to ask the authors of that change what they thought they were achieving with that change.

My take is as follows:

- Changing from `notifyAll()` to `notify()` is a good thing.  If there are `N` threads waiting on a queue's `offerLock` or `pollLock`, then this avoids `N - 1` unnecessary wakeups.
- It seems that the counters are being used avoid calling `notify()` when there isn't a thread waiting.  This looks to me like a doubtful optimization.  AFAIK a `notify` on a mutex when nothing is waiting is very cheap.  So this may make a small difference ... but it is unlikely to be significant.
- If you really want to know, write some benchmarks.  Write 4 versions of this class with no optimization, the notify optimization, the counter optimization and both of them.  Then compare the results ... for different levels of queue contention.

---

I'm not sure what "fairness" is supposed to mean here, but I can't see anything in this class to guarantee that threads that are waiting in `offer` or `poll` get treated fairly.

Answer (score 1):

> Another thought is that they may have something to do with the switch from notifyAll to notify, but again I think we can safely use notify even without them?

Yes, since two locks (`pollLock`  and `offerLock`) are used, it is no problem to change `notyfiAll` to `notify` without these two variables. But if you are using a lock, you must use `notifyAll`.

> My understanding is that the 2 variables purpose is that you won't do useless notify calls when there's nothing wait on the object. But what harm would it do if not done this way?

Yes, these two variables are to avoid useless `notify` calls. These two variables also bring in additional operations. I think benchmarking may be needed to determine performance in different scenarios.

Besides,

1.As a blocking queue, it should implement the interface `BlockingQueue`, and both `poll` and `offer` methods shoule be `non-blocking`. It should use `take` and `put`.

2.This is not a `Fairness` queue.